# SSH config for minimal typing when connecting via bastion host

Tags: ssh

For connecting to a device via jump proxy (bastion host), I type the following:

ssh -J bhost myuser@localhost -p $PORT

`myuser` is the usernanme for my current logged in user on my local device as well as the account I am connecting to on the bastion host. I have more than one PORT set up.

`bhost` is defined in my SSH .config like this:

```
Host bhost
  HostName www.example.com
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

My goal is to not have to type `myuser@localhost`. Instead, I want to be able to login like this:

```
ssh -J bhost -p $PORT
```

No matter the bastion host or port I use, `myuser@localhost` is always the same, so I prefer to not have to type it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to expand on the entries in your `~/.ssh/config` file. Maybe something like the following would work.  You'll need to play around with it, because I feel like your question isn't really giving enough information.

`.ssh\config`:

```
# this entry is the one you're trying to ssh to
Host example
  Hostname www.example.com
  ProxyJump bhost

# this entry is the bastion (jump) host
Host bhost
  Hostname www.example.com
  Port 8022
  User myuser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

You're really just setting up two different hosts in the `.ssh/config` and telling one to use the other via a `ProxyJump` command.

Then `ssh example` would be all you need to type to jump all the way through to the desired target machine.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The port doesn't belong to the bastion host. It is associated with the other entry.

Answer (score 0):

Answer inspired by [Tim Kennedy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4721/tim-kennedy). As he said, this can be done via the ~/.ssh/config file.

Here is a working solution:

```
Host bhost
  HostName www.example.com
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host example1
  Hostname localhost
  User myuser
  Port 22021
  ProxyJump bhost
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host example2
  Hostname localhost
  User myuser
  Port 28022
  ProxyJump bhost
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host example3
  Hostname localhost
  User myuser
  Port 28023
  ProxyJump bhost
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Each target device needs a unique port number. They also have a common hostname of `localhost`. The bastion host is an actual domain name, of course.

With this config, you can get to any of the end targets with:

```
ssh example1
```

Or

```
ssh exampleN
```